# How to fetch user selected model fields in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I wanted to fetch the data from database according to the data selected by user input. I'am using model_name.objects.all which fetches all the data from that model.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.conf import settings


class quiztitle(models.Model):

    Quiz_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    Quiz_title = models.CharField(max_length=600)
    User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
    User_id= models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    no_of_ques = models.IntegerField(default=10)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.Quiz_title

class question(models.Model):
    Qid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
    User_id = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Quiz_id = models.ForeignKey(quiztitle,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Qques = models.TextField()
    Qoption1 = models.TextField()
    Qoption2 = models.TextField()
    Qoption3 = models.TextField()
    Qoption4 = models.TextField()
    QAnswer = models.TextField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.Qques

class answer(models.Model):

    Ansid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    Qid = models.OneToOneField(question,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Quiz_id = models.ForeignKey(quiztitle, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
    User_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Answer = models.TextField()


class result(models.Model):
    result = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    Quiz_id = models.OneToOneField(quiztitle, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    User_id = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    score = models.FloatField()


def __str__(self):
    return str(self.pk)
```

here's html file from which user selects the quiz title to start the quiz. By clicking on the attempt quiz button user can attempt there choosen quiz .
student.html

```
 <div class="Question-container">
     <div>
         {% for x in title %}
         <h1 class="title"><i class="fa fa-circle" id="quiz-icon" ></i>{{x.Quiz_title}}<button onclick="window.location.href='/sample'">Attempt Quiz</button></h1>
         {% endfor %}
    </div>

 </div>
```

main problem ->sample.html(here is wanted to fetch the data of selected quiz_title which is listed in student.html)

```
<body>
    <div class="topnav">
        <div class="topnav-right">
          <a href="{% url 'home' %}" class="aa">Home</a>
          <a href="{% url 'logout' %}" class="aa">Logout  </a>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="leftbar">
    <div>
        {% for x in title %}
        <h1 class="title">{{x.Quiz_title}}</h1>
        <input type="hidden" id="Quiz_id" value="{{x.Qid}}">
         {% endfor %}
    </div>

    {% for x in ques %}
        <h1 class="question" >Q. {{x.Qques}}</h1>
        <input type="hidden" id="Qid" value="{{x.Qid}}">

    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="radio"><label><input type="radio" id="option1"  name="name" value="{{x.Qoption1}}">{{x.Qoption1}}</label></div>
        <div class="radio"><label><input type="radio" id="option2"  name="name" value="{{x.Qoption2}}">{{x.Qoption2}}</label></div>
        <div class="radio"><label><input type="radio" id="option3"  name="name" value="{{x.Qoption3}}">{{x.Qoption3}}</label></div>
        <div class="radio"><label><input type="radio" id="option4"  name="name" value="{{x.Qoption4}}">{{x.Qoption4}}</label></div>


    {% endfor %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"  id="save_ans">Save</button>
    </div></form>
    <div class="paginator">
   <div class="form-group">
       {% if ques.has_previous %}
       <a href="?page={{ques.previous_page_number}}"><button class="btn-back" id="submitAnswer">Back</button></a>
       {% endif %}
       {% if ques.has_next %}
       <a href="?page={{ques.next_page_number}}"><button class="btn-next" id="submitAnswer">Next</button></a>
       {% else %}
       <a href="/result/"><button type="submit" class="btn  btn-success" id="submitAnswer">Submit Quiz</button></a>
       {% endif %}
   </div>
```

I want to fetch the data i.e question along with the option of the quiztitle chosen  by the user But question.objects.all() is giving all the questions stored in the table. kindly help me to improve the logic.

views.py

```
def handle_res(request):
myuser = User.objects.all()
title = quiztitle.objects.all()
ques = question.objects.all()
if request.method == 'POST':
    Answer = request.POST.get('ans')
    print("Answer",Answer)
    Quiz_id = request.POST.get('Quiz_id')
    print("Quizid",Quiz_id)
    Qid = request.POST.get('Qid')
    print("questionid",Qid)
    quizid = quiztitle(Quiz_id=Quiz_id)
    quesid = question(Qid=Qid)

    response = answer(Answer=Answer)
    response.User_id = request.user
    response.Quiz_id = quizid
    response.Qid = quesid
    response.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/response')

return render(request, "sample.html", context={"ques": ques, "title": title, "myuser": myuser})
```

Answer (score 2):

I would like to make few changes to the code.
First in HTML, you have creating multiple elements with same ID using for loop. Please remove that.

```
{% for x in title %}
         <h1 class="title"><i class="fa fa-circle" id="quiz-icon" ></i>{{x.Quiz_title}}<button>Attempt Quiz</button></h1>
         {% endfor %}
```

Coming to your question, I would do something like this.

1. Changing buttons to link with parameter as quizID

```
{% for x in title %}
         <h1 class="title"><i class="fa fa-circle" id="quiz-icon" ></i>{{x.Quiz_title}}<a href="/attempt-quiz/{{x.Quiz_id}}/">Attempt Quiz</a></h1>
         {% endfor %}
```

2. Create url for it in urls.py file

```py
path('attempt-quiz/<str:i>/',views.attempt_quiz,name="attempt_quiz"),
```

3. Write the view function

```py
def attempt_quiz(request,i):  
quiz_obj = quiztitle.objects.get(id=i)
questions = question.objects.filter(Quiz_id=quiz_obj)
return render........
```

You get all the question objects. Now you can access all the information of objects (options and all) using . operator

```py
for i in questions:
print(i.Quiz_id.Quiz_title)
print(i.Qques)
print(i.Qoption1)
print(i.Qoption2)
print(i.Qoption3)
print(i.Qoption4)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some things you doing wrong in here:

1. Your class names should be writing using camel casing
2. Your class attributes should be written in lowercase
3. Make sure you leave spaces between your model attributes and method definitions.
4. We can't really see what's making the request, what's triggering the button? I don't know if you are requesting the content making use of JS because i can't see any link or 'a' tag wrapping the button.

As i said, you need to make sure to use the .filter() method from Query Set manager, it accepts the class attributes as parameters as follows:

model.objects.filter(attribute=your_request). Hope this helps! If you need help make me know.

```
def handle_res(request):
myuser = User.objects.all()
title = quiztitle.objects.filter(quiztitle=your_title) # Code Changed
ques = question.objects.all()
if request.method == 'POST':
    Answer = request.POST.get('ans')
    print("Answer",Answer)
    Quiz_id = request.POST.get('Quiz_id')
    print("Quizid",Quiz_id)
    Qid = request.POST.get('Qid')
    print("questionid",Qid)
    quizid = quiztitle(Quiz_id=Quiz_id)
    quesid = question(Qid=Qid)

    response = answer(Answer=Answer)
    response.User_id = request.user
    response.Quiz_id = quizid
    response.Qid = quesid
    response.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/response')

return render(request, "sample.html", context={"ques": ques, "title": title, "myuser": myuser})
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.. I've edited my question to provide few more details...It is still fetching all the questions stored in the question table...my concern is to fetch only those fields from the question table whose quiztitle is same as the quiztitle choosen by the user(as user clicks on attempt quiz button in student.html) please help its my minor project .

Comment: student.html is displaying a list of all the titles present ij the quiztitle table. so user comes and selects one title eg: he selects "Python MCQs" and is directed to the sample.html page to attempt his quiz but here problem is here all the question present in the question table is displayed, Only the question present for "Python MCQs" title should be fetched from the question table. question.objects.all is not working in place of this was trying to use  questions.objects.filter(quiz_title='that quiz_title input given by  user in student.html ') how can i do this?